# Proof: $x_n\to p \iff d(x_n,p)\to 0$

Tags: metric-spaces

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, let ${x_n}\in M$ and $p\in M$
>
> Prove: $x_n\to p \iff d(x_n,p)\to 0$

$\Leftarrow:$ be definition of a limit, for all $0  < \varepsilon$ there is $N\leq n$ such that $$|d(x_n,p) + 0|< \varepsilon \iff |d(x_n,p)|< \varepsilon \iff d(x_n,p)< \varepsilon$$

last $\iff$ is due to $d:M\times M\to [0,\infty)$

$\Rightarrow:$ $x_n\to p$, let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ therefore for all $N\leq n$
$$0 \leq d(x_n,p)<\frac{1}{n}$$ using the squeeze theorem we get $$d(x_n,p)\to 0$$

Have I missed something? is it correct?

Comment: How have you defined convergence in a metric space? This seems a bit tautological

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideas are all there, but your argument is somewhat muddled. Note the ordering, especially when it comes to $N$ and $n$:

If $d(x_n,p) \to 0$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for any $n \geq N$ we have $$d(x_n,p) < \epsilon.$$ 
(Absolute values not necessary as distances are non-negative.)
But this is precisely the condition for $x_n \to p$ in a metric space, so the two statements are equivalent.